# How to update memcached in Django Rest API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have been setting up caching in Django using a database cache but problem is when changes in database using Rest API PUT method but cache data not change instantly, after some time value should be reflected.

**using below code refer:**

```
## setting.py

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware’,
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

Please help me out. I not saw Memcached Status and Memcached store Data.
Anyone to suggested how to do that?

Comment: Add more granularity to your cache, update/remove cache keys explicitly.

Comment: @IvanStarostin how to see mamcached data in centos local because does not know the key?. can you explain in detail?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#accessing-the-cache